# Video upload with Graph API from user's desktop

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, video, graph, upload

i am trying to upload a local video to Facebook through the Graph API.
Here is an example from Facebook:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/
That works nice, and i get an JSON response after submitting the from.
How can I get the respone ID, for use in, e.g. Javascript or directly as an GET-parameter on my server?
I don't want to upload the video on an public accessable server and then redirect the video upload to Facebook by using curl or something like that.

Has anyone an idea or an example of how i can get this to work?

---

Edit:

Here is the example i used:

```
<?php 
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET"; 
$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL"; 
$video_title = "YOUR_VIDEO_TITLE";
$video_desc = "YOUR_VIDEO_DESCRIPTION";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
   $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
     . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
     . "&scope=publish_stream";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
    . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
    . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc 
    . "&". $access_token;

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" '.$post_url.' "  
     method="POST">';
echo 'Please choose a file:';
echo '<input name="file" type="file">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

Taken from this page: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/

This is the whole response i get from the form (JSON response):

```
{
    "id": "xxxxx19208xxxxx"
}
```

The problem is that the JSON response is inline in the page.
I thought to set a target in the form to an inline iframe but then i will not be able to access the JSON code.

Comment: Can you please include some more inforrmation?  Some code samples of what you have tried, the `JSON` response that you refer to, etc...

Comment: Use Javascript to submit the form via an AJAX request so that you can handle the response in JS too.